# can we porting ART(android runtime) in non android arm Linux?

Tags: android, linux, runtime

if ART runtime is open source then is it possible to port it to other linuxes?
Or using the compiled binaris in other linuxes?
What about adding the art (android runtime) to the linux at build?I mean some new code in the repo and make file.